How can I instruct SSDT to ignore generated constraint names during deployment?
My database contains a table defined like this
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [TradeBlockId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__MyTableO__78D4AEA3FD2A1608] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TradeBlockId] ASC, [TradeAllocationId] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTableOv__LastU__623C3574]  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [LastUpdatedDate]

While my project does not specify constraint names
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [TradeBlockId]    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
    [LastUpdatedDate] DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TradeBlockId] ASC, [TradeAllocationId] ASC)
);

I would like the deployment to ignore these names... But cannot find the right option
Is it possible?
Something like "Ignore system generated names"
Thanks

"While my project does not specify constraint names' why are you specifying names for your constraints in the first place? You should be.

It's a VERY old project that used to be maintained/deployed through Redgate. Trying to move to SSDT but there is already a LOT of code... And we do specify constraint names in many places as well

What actual issue are you seeing with this? From a quick test at least for key constraints it seems to ignore these anyway and not do anything with them in the publish file if is_system_named in the server and unnamed in the project

Actually... I am confused! I tried creating a small table with no constraint names on PK and Date default... and SQL Server did not invent any names at all... I wonder where these names I see in our tables come from... Maybe something historical?...

@MartinSmith - fwiw, an issue that I've seen historically with this sort of thing is that someone creates a constraint in a dev environment and then uses a schema sync tool (e.g. something as unsophisticated as scripting the object out to Redgate SQL Compare) and the is_system_named property gets lost in the shuffle because the generated script explicitly uses the system generated name. At which point the name is now important to subsequent comparisons. You can say "don't do that" all you want, but reality often doesn't match the Platonic ideal.

You are right, it looks like this is what happened here. They had system like names but were not system names anymore...

Thanks Martin Smith, the answer was that my "apparently" system named constraints were not system_named anymore.
They had been recreated at some stage re-using the default constraint names initially system generated.
SELECT name, DC.is_system_named
FROM sys.default_constraints DC
WHERE name LIKE '%[__][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]%'
